# Recaptcha v3: Could not connect to the reCAPTCHA service. Please check your internet connection and reload to get a reCAPTCHA challenge

Tags: recaptcha, captcha, recaptcha-v3

I am using recaptcha v3, and if i put my pc on a sleep, then awake it, my web site form shows me error saying:

> Could not connect to the reCAPTCHA service. Please check your internet
>   connection and reload to get a reCAPTCHA challenge.

How can i solve it?
P.S. If i refresh page everything is fine.

Comment: Did you find an answer?  If so, please post